# Error when running the app, firebase_auth_oauth_web not found?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Plugin project :firebase_auth_oauth_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find com.google.firebase:fir55554ebase-bom:26.4.0.
> Required by:
> project :app

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: If you're hot reloading or hot restarting then that might not work, stop the running application and rerun it, this might help.

Comment: you should always use the latest version of Firebase services in your pubspec.yaml file